# How to restore "DASH" button functionality

Tags: unity, unity-dash

Don't know what I did to make this happen.   My Dash icon was functioning properly now whenever I press the dash (or the super key) my desktop goes to the user log-in screen

Answer (score 0):

Try this and enter this in the terminal:

```
 dconf reset -f /org/compiz
 unity --reset-icon &disown
```

and it might work fine this way.